# ASP .NET MVC web service and PostRepository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I´m a newbie in ASP .NET MVC technology .
Actually my question is:

Is a PostRepository, used in ASP .NET MVC web app ([like this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1155/aspnet-mvc-repository-pattern-perform-database-operations)) working as WebService? Or basicaly, when I have `ActionResult` method in Controller i.e. for deleting some post from db based on PostId as paramether of this method (/post/delete/5 for example) is this web service? Or it´s just a mechanism that MVC use for performing CRUD operations so it´s not a webservice?

It´s true, that `ActionResults` methods of controller returnig Views are not web services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository pattern is helping you to keep a clear code structure. It explains you how and where to keep the database access functions.

This way you don't overcrowd your code in the controller. Plus you can recycle the code, calling the same function from two different places.

For creating rest web services you should use Web API. And the result of an web service is not an view; it is usually an object.

Returning a View means that you want to display a page and not a service.

Comment: And how about areas? When I want to break a code to some logical part (modules) which will not run separately, but with main app - I can just turn off this modules or turn on and code is separatelly grouped for one functionality in area. This areas are no web services, am I right?  @alex-suleap

Comment: Areas are just logical grouping of controllers so you can keep a good folder structure. That is all. They won't affect your final routes.

Comment: As example: Your applications needs an admin and an user. You can put the the admin controllers into one area and the user controllers in the second one. And you got a clearer code structure.

Comment: I´ve got several areas - for example area for document publishing - with own model. controller and view. Route is: localhost/publishedDocument. Then I have main MVC not in area where are post Url > localhost/post/postId. Is this correct? Thanks for answers!

Comment: Areas are normally used when you want to build very big application. Regarding the url paths I recommend you to read a little about routing. If you want to see localhost/publishedDocument in your browser you just need to creat the PublishedDocumentController class and add an index view.